# How to repeat and end repeat local notification is iOS 10?

Tags: swift, ios10, nscalendar, localnotification

The system app 'Reminder' can set repeat and end repeat, but iOS 10`UserNotification.framework` not support this function.
I using the `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` to push local notification. How can i implement the repeat and end repeat function? Thanks.

```
let dateC = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute], from: startDate!)

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateC, repeats: true)

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "title"
content.body = "body"

let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: testIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

center.add(request) { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    print("scheduled")
}
```

Comment: Have you got the answer? I am also having the same issue.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do it yet. @Learner

Comment: There is no end repeat function so we need to remove notification.

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["my.notificationIdentifier"])
@zhi zhou

Comment: But how do you delete a notification if the user doesn't open your app? @Learner

Comment: I agree we cannot end a repeated local notification when app is in suspended state, so we have to delete that notification whenever the app get launch again either by clicking on app icon or by clicking on notification.